# How to show the soft keyboard when a phisycal keyboard is attached in Android?

Tags: android, keyboard, soft-keyboard

In my app I need to use a Bluetooth barcode scanner as my input. When I pair the Bluetooth keyboard, a physical input keyboard will be recognized and from that point the soft keyboard will not pop up.

The question is how can I choose the soft/hard keyboard for any specific EditText field in my layouts?